# Why Approx_Count_distinct and count(distinct) use together can improve the performance?

Tags: sql-server, performance

Can some one tell me why the performance is much better when my query
use Approx_Count_distinct and count(distinct) in the same query?

Brief Background
My PTransaction table is over 100 million rows
My Users table is over million rows

execution plan

without APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HyAqIBovj

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HkTJUroDs

```
 -- spent 1:43 to run
SELECT TransactionTypeId
                , count(1) as [Count]
                , sum(BetAmount) as [TotalBetAmount]
                , sum(PayoutAmount) as [TotalPayoutAmount]
                , sum(ResultAmount) as [TotalResultAmount]
                , count(distinct PlayerId) as [PlayerCount]
                FROM PTransaction 
            WHERE 
                ResultTime >= @local_StartResultTime 
                and ResultTime < @local_EndResultTime   
                and TransactionStatusId in (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@local_TransactionStatusIdsCommaString, ','))
                and TransactionTypeId in (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@local_TransactionTypeIdsCommaString, ','))
                and PlayerId in(SELECT Id from Users where TenantId = @local_TenantId)
            group by TransactionTypeId
```

```
-- with Approx_Count_distinct function it only spent 27s to run 
    SELECT TransactionTypeId
                , count(1) as [Count]
                , sum(BetAmount) as [TotalBetAmount]
                , sum(PayoutAmount) as [TotalPayoutAmount]
                , sum(ResultAmount) as [TotalResultAmount]
                , count(distinct PlayerId) as [PlayerCount]
                , Approx_Count_distinct (PlayerId) as [PlayerCount_Approx]
                FROM PTransaction 
            WHERE 
                ResultTime >= @local_StartResultTime 
                and ResultTime < @local_EndResultTime   
                and TransactionStatusId in (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@local_TransactionStatusIdsCommaString, ','))
                and TransactionTypeId in (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@local_TransactionTypeIdsCommaString, ','))
                and PlayerId in(SELECT Id from Users where TenantId = @local_TenantId)
            group by TransactionTypeId
```

Comment: Upload the actual execution plans to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and add the links to your question.

Comment: execution plan is added

Comment: Add the plan for the query without `APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT` too.

Comment: execution plan is added , thx a lot

Comment: Different plan shapes are the reason for the performance difference. The version without `APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT` uses stream agg operators with an ordered stream whereas the version with `APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT` uses hash match agg operators, which need not be ordered and is more efficient for both aggregations in this case. 
I suggest you ask this question on dba.stackexchange.com if you want a detailed explanation as to why SQL Server chose stream agg for the version without `APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT`.

Comment: I can't see your plan because of the Brent Ozar website disapear... But the algorithm that is used in APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT (by Flajolet) is very fast and use very few memory and can drive the classicak count distinct to a better more evalusation of resources needed then change some operators...

Comment: I reposted the Plan. Hope you can see.
without APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HyAqIBovj
with
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJpzCmhwj
As you said APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT can drive the classical count distinct to a better more evalusation of resources , is that mean it is a good practice to use count(distinct) and APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT together to improve the preformance?